# Set an image extracting the file name from JSON file

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to set an ImageView by getting the name of the image from a JSON file

This method is in my custom RecyclerView adapter. The getImage returns a String with the name of the image but it says it needs an int.

How can I resolve this?

```
 @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BirdView holder, int position) {
       holder.birdImage.setImageResource(birdList.get(position).getImage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `Context` in Adapter constructor and save as a field `mContext`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BirdView holder, int position) {
    holder.birdImage.setImageResource(Utility.getDrawableFromName(mContext ,birdList.get(position).getImage());
}
```

write this method in your Utility.java class

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromName(Context context,String name){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the glide library for it!

for using the glide library open your build.gradle(Module:app) and add these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
}
```

then go to your adapter class load your image like this :

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BirdView holder, int position) {

    Glide.with(context)
                .load(birdList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.birdImage);
    }
```

this is the process we all follow to load an image into image view from JSON response